# Error: Operations must use an updatable query

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I Created a program which will check into a hotel and update the back-end.
I am having a problem connecting and changing the UserID on my Rooms Table.
Tables are :

---

### Users:

```
UserID - PK, Auto Number
Username - Short Text
Password - Short Text
```

---

### Rooms

```
RoomID - PK, Auto Number
Room_Number - Number
UserID - FK, Number
```

---

### Updatable Query

```
PARAMETERS parUsername Short, parRoom_Number Short;
UPDATE Rooms SET UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Username = [parUsername])
WHERE Room_Number=[parRoom_Number];
```

---

### C# Code

### Form1

```
MessageBox.Show("Login Successful");
Home home = new Home();
home.Show();
home.LabelText = this.txtUsername.Text;
```

---

### Home Form

```
public string LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.lblUsername.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                this.lblUsername.Text = value;
            }
        }
```

---

### CheckIn Usercontrol

```
 Home home = new Home();
            try
            {
                string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/Hotel.accdb";
                using (var con = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.CommandText = "Query2";
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("parUsername", home.LabelText);
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("parRoom_Number", lbRooms.SelectedItem);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Try `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = "EXEC Query2";`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Still giving me the error: Operation must use an updatable query

Comment: Try: `...UserID IN (SELECT...)...`

Comment: @June7 Gives Syntax error: Error in UPDATE Statement

Comment: Sorry, I misread the SQL. Can't set a field to a nested subquery. This is trying to set the field to a set of records, not a single value.

Comment: @June7 So how would i get t to find the UserID when i have the Username and put the UserID as the value for the update query?

Comment: In VBA I would probably use DLookup. But appears there is an answer offered for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a sub-query, try this

```
PARAMETERS parUsername Text ( 255 ), parRoom_Number Long;
UPDATE Rooms, Users SET Rooms.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE Rooms.Room_Number = [parRoom_Number] AND Users.Username = [parUsername];
```

Comment: Its not giving me the error anymore but it doesn't update anything in the database.

Comment: I made a test. It works for me. But you might adapt the types of the parameters to closely match those in your tables.

Comment: Thanks the problem was in the c# code i didnt put 
.ToString() on the home.LabelText

Answer (score 0):

First I altered the Query2 stored procedure. Passing the User ID and Room number (changed this to a Number datatype to match the table definition (not a Short as in you question.)

```
PARAMETERS parUserID Number, parRoom_Number Number;
UPDATE Rooms SET UserID = [parUserID]
WHERE Room_Number=[parRoom_Number];
```

Then I modified your code to a separate query to get the UserId.

```
        Home home = new Home();
        int userID;
        try
        {
            string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "/Hotel.accdb";
            using (var con = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
            {
                con.Open();
                //Passing the query and the connection directly to the constructor
                using (OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Username = @UserName;", con))
                {
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = home.LabelText;
                    userID = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
                }
                using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "Query2";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("parUserID", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = userID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("parRoom_Number",OleDbType.Numeric ).Value = (int)lbRooms.SelectedItem;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
         }

         catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below option, it should work

`UPDATE Rooms A,(SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE Username = 'Test') B SET A.UserID = B.UserID WHERE Room_Number=1;`